# How to add data after existing childs in firebase,using push()

Tags: java, android, firebase

In Firebase I am adding data using `push()`. Whenever I try to add it, it is added at top and not after existing pushed children.

How can I add a new push data after existing pushed data in realtime database?
[Here is my query from android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFtHd.png)
[This is image of my firebase consle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zWp7.png)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "added at top". Are you displaying the children in a list? Show us the code. :)

Also, please tag which language you are using: web/js, Android, iOS?

Comment: I am using java programming for android application.

Comment: @KiranRathod The best way to get help for code-related problems is by sharing the [minimum code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it's quite useful).